# Emulating touch-screens

Tags: touch, screen, emulation

How would you emulate touch-screens? I wouldn't want to pay $ to get a touch-screen to test my software whether it supports touching fully. Any links or tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sprint WTK 3.3
[Sprint](http://developer.sprint.com/site/global/develop/technologies/java_me/sdk_tools/p_sdk_tools.jsp)